# Configure IntelliJ to jump to Javascript methods called

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I am working on a legacy code and some jewel decided to call javaScript file

`GeneralJScript.txt`

Because of this (I think) IntelliJ cannot jump to method `declaration` in this file.
Is there a way I can make `IntelliJ` find it?

Comment: How about renaming the file and solving two problems at once?

Comment: @DaveNewton I did that, IntelliJ still can't go to declaration. I also have problem with not being able to go to implementation. I will keep trying. Thanks.